# Why an unsaved asterisk appears after saving for web?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

This isn't a make-or-break type of problem, just a curiosity that has bugged me for a long time. Mainly in Illustrator, but I believe photoshop as well, when I take a currently saved document and use the "save for web" feature to export a jpeg, an asterisk then appears next to the file name on the tab at the top, representing that the file needs to be saved again. Can anyone tell me why? It doesn't seem as though anything could be changed in the artwork itself. I usually command+z back a step to get rid of the asterisk, but if I save again it also gets rid of the asterisk and there seems to be no difference between the two approaches. Just a curiosity. Thanks!

Comment: The same "unsaved" indicator does appear after using Save for Web in Photoshop, and if you then close the image it'll prompt you to save unsaved changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a similar question regarding InDesign and PDFs here somewhere. But darned if I can find it.

Basically.. the *file* saves the name of the export/web image. So that next time it'll default to the same name (allowing you to overwrite easily).

The software is just storing the file name you used. If you don't care about that, you don't have to save after using Save for Web.

Thanks to @AndrewH .. here's that Indesign question... [inDesign document becomes "unsaved" after pdf export](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49571/indesign-document-becomes-unsaved-after-pdf-export)

Comment: Thank you sir! And thank you @AndrewH as well. There's a number of things that I understand how to get around them, but I'm scratching my head as to why the program works that way.